# Getting the coordinates of vertices of an A4 sheet with coins on it, for its further projective transformation and coin detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I need to transform my tilted image in a way I can find coins on an A4 paper. So far, I have been getting four coordinates of edges of my paper by manually selecting them with ginput.

```
targetImageData = imread('coin1.jpg');
imshow(targetImageData);
fprintf('Corner selection must be clockwise or anti-clockwise.\n');
[X,Y] = ginput(4);
```

Is there a way to automate this process, say, apply some edge detector and then find coordinates of each vertex and then pass them as the coordinates needed for transformation?

Manual selection:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am actually using imfindcircles here, my problem is that the images are taken at different angles and I need to get my radii to be more or less unchanged for every picture I use.That is why I project them based on four points which are the vertices of my A4, I only need to automate this part

Comment: After posting, I read the question again, and realized you are looking for the corners of the paper. I think you can place a better setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [detectHarrisFeatures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectharrisfeatures.html) on the **S** color channel of HSV color space:

I was looking for a color space that gets maximum contrast of the paper.
It looks like the saturation color channel of HSV makes a good contrast between the paper and the background.

Image is resized the image by a factor of 0.25, for removing noise.

`detectHarrisFeatures` finds the 4 corners of the paper, but it might not be robust enough.
You may need to find more features, and find the 4 correct features, using some logic.

Here is a code sample:

```
%Read input image
I = imread('im.png');

%Remove the margins, and replace them using padding (just because the image is a MATLAB figure)
I = padarray(I(11:end-10, 18:end-17, :), [10, 17], 'both', 'replicate');

HSV = rgb2hsv(I);

%H = HSV(:, :, 1);%figure;imshow(H);title('H');
S = HSV(:, :, 2);%figure;imshow(S);title('S');
%V = HSV(:, :, 3);%figure;imshow(V);title('V');

%Reduce image size by a factor of 0.25 in each axis
S = imresize(S, 0.25);

%S = imclose(S, ones(3)); %May be requiered

%Detect corners
corners = detectHarrisFeatures(S);

imshow(S); hold on;
plot(corners.selectStrongest(4));
```

Result:
[image]

---

Different approach you may try:

- Take a photo without the coins.
- Mark the corners manually, and extract features of the 4 corners.
- Use [image matching](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/matchfeatures.html) techniques to match the image with the coins with the image without the coins (mach basted on the 4 corners).

Comment: Thank you, your solution seems to be fairly robust for most of the pictures from my dataset, it does find the corners of the paper most of the time. Now, I guess I should try extracting the value of corners.celestStrongest(4) and assigning it to my [X,Y] array which enganges in further logic.

Comment: Right, after engaging, you can fine tune the search at full resolution, around the coarse position.